# send multiple .crt certificate with curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I want to send two .crt certificates with curl in php.
I am using this code.

```
$firstcalldata = "csv file data";
$target_url = www.example.com;
$ch = curl_init($target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,"C:/Users/admin/Desktop/CERT/PSCERT.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/CERT/PSCERT-C.crt");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $firstcalldata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:  application/csv'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);`
```

I am sending also a csv file to $target_url.

But all time I am getting 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Comment: You should use `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` to give the path to the PEM file.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really saying what you want to accomplish, you're just asking a very weird question with no answer. You example doesn't send the .crt at all, it uses it to verify the server's certificate. And [CAINFO](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html) is meant to point to a file holding a full bundle (like one of those you can get at [curl's caextract page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html))

But you disable both VERIFYPEER and VERIFYHOST so you don't actually need any CA cert!?

What exactly do you want to do? Note also how getting a 403 back means that you already communicate fine over the TLS layer.